# How to calculate x kilometers from a lat/lon

Tags: algorithm, geolocation

I have a lat/lon and I'd like to calculate X kilometers North South East and West from that location. How would I go about doing that?

I read that "The number of kilometers per degree of longitude is approximately"

```
(2*pi/360) * r_earth * cos(theta)
Where theta is the latitude in degrees and r_earth is approximately 6378 km.
```

I'm not sure, for instance, how to calculate 3km North of a 37.875942,-122.3156416

Comment: How accurate do you want your result to be? Is this just an approximation based on assuming the Earth is a smooth sphere? If so then if you know the Earth's radius and some basic trigonometry it's not difficult.
So either you don't know trig or you want something more accurate - which is the issue? (Genuine question)

Comment: @adrianmcmenamin It doesn't have to be exact, we could assume it's a smooth sphere.

Honestly, I don't know trig and would appreciate an example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: OK, for a really simple example like the one you quote you don't really need any trigonometry at all - just to know that there are 90 degrees of latitude between the equator and the pole and so for your example: new altitude is (3/(6378 * (pi/2))) * 90 + 37.875942 and the longitude is the same. Other (real world) examples will like require some trig

Comment: Why is someone asking for an algorithm not a programming question?

Comment: You could look at sites which give the formulas assuming a spherical earth, such as http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html